# Is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate or Groupby clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I tried to sum the values based on a condition but when i tried the query I'm getting an error.

I need to sum the values if the case condition satisfies else I don't want that case condition(Summing the values) to be executed.(To activate the case condition I have set a variable(@rcntInputunit to 2) and the query should work even when the case is inactive (@rcntInputunit to 1).

The code I tried the query is shown below.

```
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @rcntInputunit AS INT
   SET @rcntInputunit =2
   CREATE TABLE #MathLogicTable
 (
     IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
     FORMULA Varchar(160),
     INPUTName varchar(160),
     AttributeValue Decimal(15,3),
     yearmonth varchar(160),
     Unit int
       )
    INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
VALUES(
'imports(398)+imports(399)',
'imports(398)',
46,
'2003:2',
15
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
VALUES(
'imports(398)+imports(399)',
'imports(399)',
3,
'2003:1',
183
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
VALUES(
'imports(398)+imports(399)',
'imports(399)',
85,
'2003:2',
15
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
VALUES(
'imports(398)+imports(399)',
'imports(399)',
12,
'2003:1',
15
)

   INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
   VALUES(
'imports(398)+imports(399)',
'imports(399)',
41,
'2003:2',
183
)


      INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
      VALUES(
          'imports(398)+imports(399)',
          'imports(398)',
           12,
          '2003:1',
           183
            )

      INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
      VALUES(
        'imports(398)+imports(399)',
        'imports(398)',
         10,
        '2003:2',
         183
              )

      INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
      VALUES(
      'imports(398)+imports(399)',
      'imports(398)',
       5,
       '2003:1',
       15
         )

Select FORMULA,INPUTName, Case when @rcntInputunit >1 THEN sum(AttributeValue) ELSE AttributeValue END AS Value ,yearmonth 
from #MathLogicTable
GROUP BY 
FORMULA,
INPUTName,
yearmonth
END
--drop table #MathLogicTable
```

Can somebody tell me what is the mistake im doing in the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` everything on your select list must be either on the `GROUP BY` list (i.e. `FORMULA`, `INPUTName`, and `yearmonth`) or be included in an aggregate function.

In your case there is one column, namely `AttributeValue` that is neither grouped on nor is aggregated.

```
Select
    FORMULA
,   INPUTName
,   Case when @rcntInputunit >1 THEN 
        sum(AttributeValue)
    ELSE
        AttributeValue -- <<== Here
    END AS Value
,   yearmonth 
from #MathLogicTable
GROUP BY 
    FORMULA
,   INPUTName
,   yearmonth
END
```

To fix this problem you need to decide which of the many items in a group you would like to provide as the `Value` column in the result, and move the condition inside `SUM`:

```
SUM(
    CASE when @rcntInputunit > 1 OR (you-want-this-row's AttributeValue) THEN 
        AttributeValue
    END
) AS Value
```